# In R is there a way to read files and check the first column of unique IDs against a predetermined list of IDs and return only those files or names?

Tags: r, read.csv, readxl

I have a folder of a few thousand files (Both .csv and .xls) and in each of these files the first column is made up of unique ID numbers.  The other fields in these files are different pieces of data that I'll need to extract with respect to that unique ID number.  The catch is that I have a list of predetermined ID numbers that I need to pull the data for.  Some files may or may not have 1 or more of my predetermined list of IDs in them.  How do I check the first column in these files against my predetermined list of IDs and return the filenames of the files that contain 1 or more of my predetermined list of IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
library(xlsx)
library(readxl) # for read_xls
my_path="C:/Users/Desktop/my_files"

# Collect the names of the files
list_doc_csv=list.files(path = my_path, pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE)
list_doc_xlsx=list.files(path = my_path, pattern = ".xlsx", all.files = TRUE)
list_doc_xls=list.files(path = my_path, pattern = ".xls", all.files = TRUE)
# Step needed as .xlsx files were select as having ".xls" patterns
list_doc_xls=list_doc_xls[which(!list_doc_xls%in%list_doc_xlsx)] 

# Declare ID of interest
ID_interesting=c("id1","id33","id101")


list_interesting_doc=c()
# Loop on CSV files and check the content of first column
for (doc in list_doc_csv){
  column1=read.csv(file=paste0(my_path,"/",doc))[,1]
  if(sum(column1%in%ID_interesting)>0){
    list_interesting_doc=c(list_interesting_doc,doc)
  }
}
# Loop on .xlsx files
for (doc in list_doc_xlsx){ 
  column1=read.xlsx(file=paste0(my_path,"/",doc),sheetIndex = 1)[,1]
  if(sum(column1%in%ID_interesting)>0){
    list_interesting_doc=c(list_interesting_doc,doc)
  }
}
# Loop on .xls files
for (doc in list_doc_xls){ 
  column1=unlist(read_xls(path=paste0(my_path, "/", doc))[,1])
  if(sum(column1%in%ID_interesting)>0){
    list_interesting_doc=c(list_interesting_doc,doc)
  }
}

print(list_interesting_doc)
```

Comment: So far it seems to be looping through the .csv files ok but I'm getting this error for the .xls and .xlsx files ( I do have the readxl; xlsx; writexl; & writeXLS packages installed):  Error in read_xls(file = paste0(my_path, "/", doc), sheetIndex = 1) : 
  unused arguments (file = paste0(my_path, "/", doc), sheetIndex = 1)                                                        am I missing a package or something?

Comment: The function read.xlsx(file=paste0(my_path,"/",doc), sheetIndex = 1) should work. However, for read_xls, the arguments are not the same than for read.xlsx. Try using  read_xls(path=paste0(my_path, "/", doc))

Comment: Thank you! your suggestions have worked.

Comment: actually I did some back checking and I feel like I might be missing something because I tested if this change in the read_xls code worked and it wasn't returning any filenames in the list_interesting_doc file.  Here's what I'm currently using:     for(doc in list_doc_xls){
  column1=read_xls(path=paste0(my_path,"/",doc))
  if(sum(column1%in%ID_interesting)>0){
    list_interesting_doc=c(list_interesting_doc,doc)
  }
}

Comment: Hi John, actually there was a specificity with output from read_xls (not a regular dataframe), I updatd my anwser to take that into account, let me know if it's working on your side too

Comment: Thanks A.FC, that reworking the read_xls code fixed that problem.  Now what am I missing on the read.xlsx?  I've re-installed tidyverse and readxl and xlsx and openxlsx packages, however, I keep getting the error in read.xlsx of unused arguments (file = paste0(my_path, "/", doc), sheetIndex = 1)

Comment: In case you have "unused arguments" errors, try entering "?read.xlsx" in the R console. You will see that there are 2 versions of read.xlsx, one with xlsx package (which I use) and the one from openxlsx. It seems that your function from openxlsx overrides the other one. If you need openxlsx package, you can just adapt the arguments (replace file by xlsxFile, and sheeIndex by sheet)